# The Great Hat Magician

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme, story

Welcome, welcome!

What an audience we have here tonight, the great Puzzling SE,
I came here with a small riddle, I hope you are all ready!
Let me put my first hat, a hat with a fat belly,
Now I am a construction block, or tools for cardistry!
Second hat now, keep focused, this one has a big head,
I can be a cacti's attack, or a very rude biped.
And another hat, with a flat top, my last tonight,
To become magic, deceptive, or exchanged for treats on one night.
Now, ladies and gentlemen, I hope you didn't find this lame,
And as I remove my hat, I must ask, **what is my name**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your name is

> Rick.

Let me put my first hat, a hat with a fat belly,
Now I am a construction block, or tools for cardistry!

> The letter B looks like it has a fat belly. A **brick** is a construction block or a case for playing cards.

Second hat now, keep focused, this one has a big head,
I can be a cacti's attack, or a very rude biped.

> The letter P has a big head. A **prick** is a sting or a rude person.

And another hat, with a flat top, my last tonight,
To become magic, deceptive, or exchanged for treats on one night.

> T with a flat head, magic **trick** as well as "trick or treat".

Comment: That is correct, but oh so soon. I hope this checkmark is enough of a boon.

Comment: And why the "R" at first place and not "M" (Mick)

Comment: @teoML Rot13: Orpnhfr "Ozvpx", "Czvpx" naq "Gzvpx" nera'g erny jbeqf…